# joomla: space appears if module is not there

Tags: css, joomla

The below code will be displayed only if user1 module is enabled

```
<?php if($this->countModules('user1')) : ?>
<div id="ja-main">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" />
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

All things are going exactly right. But the key problem is: there shows heighty space if the user1 module is disabled. That means the div is still able to script. Why is this so? How can I remove that space?

Comment: When the module in user1 is disabled, do you actually see `<div id="ja-main">` in the source code of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php if($this->countModules('user1')>0) : ?>
<div id="ja-main">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" />
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($this->countModules('user1')<1) : ?>
<div style="display: none;"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if parent div also need to be within 'if' condition.
You can also try:

if($this->countModules('user1')>0)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is still a div laying around that has a specified height. You need to identify that div and make sure that doesn't show up if there is no user module.

Can you use some sort of inspect element in your browsers tool kit (chrome has a nice one) and tell us what div is still lingering around?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($this->countModules('user1')>0) : ?>
<div id="ja-main">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" />
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($this->countModules('user1')<1) : ?>
<div style="display: block;"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The display should be block

Answer (score 0):

`<?php if($this->countModules('user1')) : ?>
            <div id="ja-main">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" />
            </div>
        <?php else if($this->countModules('user1')):?>
            <div style="display: block;">
                /* Content */
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>`